# Performance: React render a function vs render a component

Tags: performance, reactjs

Is there a performance difference in React between 1, 2 and 3?

1.

```
class App extends Component {
  renderHeader = () => <h1>Hello</h1>;

  render() {
     return <div>
       {this.renderHeader()}
     </div>;
  }
}
```

2.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return <div>
       <h1>Hello</h1>
     </div>;
  }
}
```

3.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return <div>
       <Header />
     </div>;
  }
}

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Option one has more clock cycles as opposed to option two.

Comment: Makes sense. I added a 3rd compare case. How does 1 and 3 compare?

Comment: the fist and the secod are almost the same... 99.9%. while the third one (as @brandNew said) has more clock cycles